# Global error handling in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling

Is there anything wrong with catching errors in an ASP.NET application globally (eg: Global.asax)? I have viewed the question [Good error handling practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155203/good-error-handling-practice) and it doesn't really say too much about this.

My experience has been excluding some very specific circumstances (such as transactions) most of the ASP.NET applications we are writing are along the lines of

```
void ButtonEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid) {
        //Do a database insert or update thru relevant datalayers.
        //If its a transaction then we rollback internally and rethrow
        //the exception.
    }
}
```

Why not just have a global exception handler? Usually (at this point) the only thing I can do is abort the operation gracefully and tell the user to try again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155203/good-error-handling-practice

Comment: At the same point, I usually catch known possible exceptions and display a message to the user, leaving unexpected exceptions for global handling.  You could catch all exceptions (most people argue against this) and display a message *as long as you've logged the exception*.  If you don't log the exception, it will be a huge pain to track down the error.  You may spend weeks trying to reproduce an error caused by a rare database/services hiccup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The global place to handle uncatched Exceptions would be in [Global.asax by handling `Application_Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx). As John pointed out, you should always handle exceptions as close as possible to where they might occur and react appropriately.

Comment: But hold on, my point is this.... Yes of course if I can somehow handle the exception at the source I will do so but typically the only action that remains is to log the error and abort. I mean what can I do if there is an SQL timeout for example? So why would I duplicate this code in everyone of my pages?

Comment: @MaximGershkovich exactly, I would put error handling code on `Application_Error` just for unhandled exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I think so. You should catch exceptions that you might expect on a particular operation as close to it as possible, and behave appropriately, but barring that (or perhaps following it after it does some clean-up and rethrows) a global handler that logs the exception and goes to a general 500 response is a good default behaviour.