# Is there any way to get know that catch statement is trigger

Tags: c#, asp.net, try-catch

I have created an application **with lots of try and catch for error handling** and now I want to **apply functionality that I should get email when any statement goes in catch**.
But its too hectic and time consuming for calling a function in all catch statement.

Hence **I need some suggestion or solution by which I can make a event which get triggered when any statement falls in catch statement**.

Comment: `try {...} catch (Exception e) { if (e is InvalidArgumentException) ... }` Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: I think you should read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875947/global-error-handling-in-asp-net

Comment: @oleksii: removing un-needed `try..catch` blocks let exception fall in global exception handling... am I wrong? If OP wants to have just one exception handler, he cannot use `try..catch` everywhere...

Comment: @Marco that's right. I am not sure if OP wants to remove `try-catch`

Comment: Thanks guys for suggestion but I have created the global event handler but i doesn't work in case of catch and I don't want to remove try catch because this will take same time and will generate user visible error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing available.

Some workarounds:

- Use Visual Studio *FindAll "catch"* and insert a line to rise an event
- If you use a logging framework, you can add an email logger and manually check that all exception handlers call the logger (for example see [SmtpAppender log4net config](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html))
- For unhandled exceptions you can use `global.asax` event handler

This is a manual process, unfortunately there is no such functionality available out of the box.

Comment: thanks for reply but I already done the global part and what is your suggesstion is my last solution still waiting i any method still exists